# Reconstruction 3d for a rotation camera

Tags: matlab-cvst, 3d-reconstruction

I have rotating camera images and I'm trying this example of a MATLAB computer vision toolbox (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/67383-stereo-triangulation) 
I have the calibration and rotation matrix for each image, however I always find 3d points equal to (0,0,0).
It is noted that the translation is null which makes the fourth column null.

Comment: Could you describe your question more clearly? What You want to achive, what result are you getting ??

Comment: I want to get the coordinates (xyz) of the scene knowing that I have two calibrated rotating camera images, using this example of a MATLAB computer vision toolbox (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/67383-stereo-triangulation) I only get zeros.

Comment: Could You provide from which function you getting this results and with what parameters, matlab version and code example snippet or project example repo ??

Comment: Can you please use the edit function on your question to add in the information that @SkorpEN requested? And make sure that you've got all of the appropriate tags on the question as that will get it more visibility. I've just added matlab-cvst as that seems appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reconstruct a 3D point from a rotating camera.

I suggest you try and draw an example. The idea of triangulation is to compute the intersection of two backprojection rays. These rays pass through the camera center and the point to be reconstructed. In your drawing, you'll find that the intersection becomes more and more accurate the larger the so-called stereo baseline is (that's the translation from one camera center to the other).

Now, for a rotating camera, the camera center remains the same and therefore, the two rays are identical. An intersection is not defined.

Comment: Is there any other method to suggest besides triangulation?

Comment: You cannot recover 3D information. One thing you can do, but likely won't help, is to stitch individual images together to get one large image, a panoramic image or a photo sphere...